# Сохранение и чтение данных пользователя

Tags: java, android

В процессе учебы пишу игру по сбору слов, пришел к сохранению данных:

- Очки (несколько типов).
- Имя пользователя.
- Уже собранные слова. Они хранятся в ArrayList в процессе игры. Но когда игрок выходит их надо сохранять до следующей игры.

Возник вопрос - что лучше использовать:

1. Писать в .txt (я думаю худший вариант)
2. Сохранять в SharedPreferences.
3. Начинать учить Room?

Comment: учитывая, что Вы все делаете в контексте учебы, я бы посоветовал использовать варианты 2 и 3 одновременно. Например, имя пользователя в SharedPreferences, а все остальное - в базе данных. В боевых условиях вообще сгодился бы любой из 3 вариантов, потому что вариант с .txt очень прост и быстр в реализации и его надежности и скорости вполне достаточно в рамках такой задачи

Comment: Меня интересует все же боевой вариант, наиболее оптимальный, так как игрушку в итоге хочу довести до релиза, а не просто в стол убрать. Спасибо за совет

Comment: SharedPreferences, по большому счёту, это и есть тестовый документ. Только обработка данных не нужна - не придётся парсить текст, разбивать на строки и искать нужную переменную, все делается автоматом легко и просто. Я бы остановил выбор на этом варианте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кратко - не пишите данные в файл!

Создавайте сущности например User, Achievements и Words. Сущность User будет хранить в себе следующие поля id, name, achievementsId (тут интересный момент). Необратим момент столкновения с базами данных. БД состоит из таблиц, таблицы хранят в полях данные какой либо сущности, в нашем случаи user, между таблицами существую "отношения" и БД имеют "нормальные формы" (почитайте о том, что в кавычках). Это очень просто и очевидно, вы сразу все поймете.

Быстрый старт Room https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room
Room это прекрасная ORM (ORM — технология программирования, которая связывает базы данных с концепциями объектно-ориентированных языков программирования). Она создаст смешную по простоте абстракцию для работы с БД.

LiveData наш мост между данными в таблице и готовой к работе сущностью.
LiveData - хранилище данных, работающее по принципу паттерна Observer (наблюдатель).
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#java

Поскольку Room по умолчанию запрещает запросы в основном потоке, нам нужна liveData. Вы еще здесь?

Просто в вашей UserDao. Оберните ваши данные в LiveData.

// java

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    LiveData<List<User>> getAll();
```

// kotlin

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<User>> // вот тут
```

В вашей активити подпишитесь (observe) на вашу liveData

```
myUserLiveData.observe(this, user -> {
    userTextView.setText(user.getName())
});
```

Поздравляю, вы реализовали работу с базами в вашем приложении. Асинхронно получили данные и обновили ваш интерфейс.

Answer (score 1):

Для каких-то единичных записей лучше использовать SharedPreferences, а в случае сохранения слов лучше сделать локальную бд вроде Realm или SQLLite. (по сути это та же запись в файл только уже реализованная)